# pip install web2py

Tags: python, pip, web2py

I tried to install Web2py with pip. The installation is completed successfully. But after that I don't know how to start the server. I know there are three apps which are 'w2p_clone', 'w2p_apps' and 'w2p_run'. I don't know how to use these three apps. And also I did not set up my virtual env for Web2py, however even I do not have virtual env I can start Web2py sever from src code (like python web2py.py)

I just want to know how to use pip intall for Web2py.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can give my answer to my own question: we don't need to install web2py, just download it and python it.

Answer (score 0):

'python web2py.py' starts the server which automatically launches your default web browser. After giving a password, you can see the web2py admin interface, from where you create your apps or study the example apps.

The corresponding documentation is here:
http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03